# C, write system call, writing int

Tags: c, low-level

I found this source in Jon Erickson's book, [Hacking: The Art of Exploitation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271441),

```
userid = getuid(); // get the real user ID
// Writing data
if(write(fd, &userid, 4) == -1)  // write user ID before note data
    fatal("in main() while writing userid to file");
write(fd, "\n", 1); // terminate line
```

I tried to compile this code, and found that on the file I write, userid (which is what I write in the code above) is not right; they just wrote strange character (I think is not important to write it here). So the problem is I am trying to pass an `int` to a function which required `char *`, because of that the result on file I want to write is false.

So this is a bug, right?

Comment: `write(fd, &userid, 4)` writes the binary representation to the file. Your text editor won't understand it.

Comment: use `man write` (or google it). The `write` system call takes a `const void*`, not a `char*`. This is an issue with binary representation (i.e. your integer is not encoded to char's) not the integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) function expects a `void *` for its buffer; it writes arbitrary binary data.  If you need conversion to string, use `printf()`.

You don't show the declaration of `userid`, but the `write()` line should be written as:

```
if (write(fd, &userid, sizeof(userid)) != sizeof(userid))
```

This will detect short writes (unlikely to be a problem for an integer type) and other problems, and works correctly regardless of the type of `userid`.  The original version of the line is arguably buggy, therefore.  Otherwise, the bug seems to be in your expectations rather than the code per se.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a bug, rather it's a misunderstanding on your part. The `write` call will just write what's in memory, the binary representation. You would need something like `fprintf` to get a readable version.

For example, the binary representation of 7 may be the four bytes 0, 0, 0 and 7, which are unlikely to look like the textual representation, a single byte 55 (assuming ASCII).

It's also a bad idea to hardcode type lengths like 4 for an integer since that's not portable. Better would be to use something like `sizeof(userid)`.

Comment: thanks, I got it.
There's no bug on those source code.it just write out what in memory. which is 4 bit (the normal size of an <code> integer </code>